# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MarketShare_Display'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've been researching for several days on this but none of the suggestions made elsewhere have fixed this problem. The site starts out with classic ASP and runs OK until navigating to this page where ASP.NET is required:

```
Server Error in '/MDS' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"    Inherits="MarketShare_Display" CodeBehind="MarketShare.aspx.vb" %>
Line 2:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
Line 3:  <html>
Source File: /mds/Out/MarketShare.aspx    Line: 1 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET  Version:2.0.50727.5483
```

The markup has been like this (below) for years, though I recently changed CodeFile= to CodeBehind= when doing "Convert to Web Application":

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MarketShare_Display" CodeBehind="MarketShare.aspx.vb" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" />
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="Visual Basic .NET 7.1"/>
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript"/>
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
        <asp:DataGrid id="DataGrid1" style="Z-INDEX: 101; LEFT: 296px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 168px"
            runat="server"></asp:DataGrid>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The MarketShare.aspx.vb file follows:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Imports MDS.Classes
Namespace MDS
Partial Class MarketShare_Display
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private oMsg As String
    Private oRpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim oSubReportHeading As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim oSubReportFooter As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    Dim dsSubReport As New DataSet            'we bind this to oSubReportFooter if needed
    Private oUtil As New CommonFormatter
    Private oHMDA As New HMDAFormatter
    Private oCR As New MyCrystalCommon
    '   Protected WithEvents DataGrid1 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid
#Region " Web Form Designer Generated Code "
    'This call is required by the Web Form Designer.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> 
    Private Sub 
         InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init
        'CODEGEN: This method call is required by the Web Form Designer
        'Do not modify it using the code editor.
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
#End Region
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim objDataSet As DataSet = QueryDataBase()
        If oUtil.HMDAData() Then
  oRpt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("./Crystal_RPTs/Report_HMDA_Marketshare.rpt"))
        Else
 oRpt.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("./Crystal_RPTs/Report_CONV_All_Detail.rpt"))
        End If
' etcetera...
```

**Background:**

The code in this site has been in production for years on a Windows 2003 Server running IIS 6.0. It began as an ASP site ("classic ASP") and at some point new features were added that used ASP.NET (e.g. this page to format a resultset from a database as a PDF dynamically constructed by Crystal Reports).

Now I have tried to reconstitute this on Windows 2008 R2 using IIS 7.5. Using the  copied source code, I created a new web project using Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. I had a variety of minor changes to make after the Migration Report.

Now the bulk of the site is classic ASP with server side VBScript and client-side Javascript and it works as expected even the SQL database access and reporting.

**Summary:**
The few places where I navigate to an ASP.NET page as shown above I get this message - "unable to load type ..."

**Edit:**

From Object Browser, I noticed 2 namespaces; MDS and MDS.MDS ! From Project properties, I cleared the root namespace, leaving assembly name as MDS:
[image: greenshot of project properties now]

I reviewed the other .aspx files (only 5 in total), invoking "Convert to Web Application" for each and adding Namespace MDS to each CodeBehind file.

Now the same testing sequence gives a different error:

**Parser Error Message: 'MarketShare_Display' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.** The rest of the error is the same as before:

```
Source Error: 
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MarketShare_Display" CodeBehind="MarketShare.aspx.vb" %>
Line 2:  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
Line 3:  <html>
Source File: /mds/Out/MarketShare.aspx    Line: 1 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483
```

**2nd Edit:**

I changed it to read Inherits="MDS.MarketShare_Display" and sure enough the error message changed yet again (see below). Therefore, I am going to close this and pursue an overall solution differently. Thanks very much.
[image: new error message]

Comment: What happens if you change Inherits="MarketShare_Display" to Inherits="MDS.MarketShare_Display"? Also if that doesn't work just fire up ObjectBrowser from the View menu and check the fully qualified typename MarketShare_Display. I note that you have Source File: /mds/Out/MarketShare.aspx in your error so maybe your true type name is  mds.out.MarketShare_Display depending on how you've set up your project / namespace settings. If your default assembly namespace is not MDS then that will be your problem. Either way Object Browser will tell you....

Comment: If your classic asp pages all work fine then this is a .net question, and you can lose the asp-classic and vbscript tags

Comment: @John - tags removed.

Comment: @rism - thanks for the ideas which I tried to follow and please see my EDIT of the OP to show how error msg has changed.

Comment: @JohnAdams I still don't see that you've changed Inherits="MarketShare_Display" to Inherits="MDS.MarketShare_Display" in the markup file. So do that first and change nothing else. If that doesn't work then in the ObjectBrowser find the MarketShare_Display class and ensure it's namespace is MDS.MarketShare_Display and that it inherits System.Web.Ui.Page. Since MarketShare_Display is a partial class also make sure that if you have any other parts floating about that they too have the same namespace otherwise they are effectively different classes and probably dont inherit from System.Web.Ui.Page

Comment: Re: The MDS and MDS.MDS. From memory in vb if you have a default root namespace and you also give your class a namespace then unlike c# where the class namespace "wins", vb compiler will add rootnamespace.classnamespace so that's how you get MDS.MDS. I see that you've cleared rootnamespace now, but going forward you should choose to use either the rootnamespace option or set the namespaces individually in the code files. This can be a frustrating oversight because the compiler / parser errrors seem to be conflicting with what we see without realising that on run there is voodoo taking place.

Comment: @rism - thanks for all your help and advice. Please see my 2nd edit. Also, please update with a summarized answer so I can check it off and give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parser errors of `could not load type` that occur on run are (in my experience) often the result of an oversight/conflict in namespaces.

When the application is run the parser will attempt a linkage between the aspx markup file and a type in the assembly. So in this case the parser is looking for `inherits=MarketShare_Display` in the application assembly.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MarketShare_Display" CodeBehind="MarketShare.aspx.vb" %>
```

Note: CodeBehind is merely a VS project linkage for development time. It means nothing at runtime.

However `MarketShare_Display` is merely a class name not a fully qualified type name. The actual FQTN for `MarketShare_Display` in this case will come from a combination of the namespace used in the class code file and whatever you have in Project Properties > RootNamespace.

In VB the namespace for the type will be rootnamespace.classnamespace, in this case MDS.MDS, before rootnamespace was made blank. Once rootnamesapce was made blank the type namepsace was MDS.

In C#, the class namespace wins if defined else the rootnamespace is used. C# does not combine the two if both are provided.

So the FQTN in this case (with rootnamespace blank) is `MDS.MarketShare_Display` but the inherits value has the parser looking for just `MarketShare_Display` hence the type not found exception.

Another potential gotcha is when you have partial classes, once with a Namespace MDS and another blank. So if you had

```
Namespace MDS
Partial Class MarketShare_Display
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

End Class
End Namespace

Partial Class MarketShare_Display
 '' other functionality here
End Class
```

In this case the parser would find the type `MarketShare_Display` but of course it does not inherit from System.Web.Ui.Page as `MDS.MarketShare_Display` is a different class than just `MarketShare_Display`. (Assuming rootnamespace is blank in a vb project).

Typically you would get a compilation error on this if you were calling functionality in both partials so it wouldn't even run but if for whatever reason you just had a an empty partial class then you can waste some minutes trying to work out why you're getting these "absurd" parser errors.

Comment: excellent summary and explanation of how this crazy issue morphed and eventually resolved. Thanks!